# limit access for search engines and user on an online development version of a site

Tags: seo, search-engines, development

I have a situation where I am having difficulties with setting up an extension for a website on my local development version of a projects. I have reached out to the support and we could not troubleshoot the problem over the email and they asked to put the dev version online and provide them ftp and admin user details.

I created a subdomain on my hosting with a ftp account, changed the admin username and password for security reasons and have everything ready to make the development version to go live, but I don't want a search engine to find the development version and start linking people to it. I know that I can disable the google analytics extension, but I think I also should change the contents of robots.txt file.

Perhaps there is something that I have not thought about or an easier way to achieve what I want. If anyone has experience with this I would be glad to read your suggestions.

PS the dev version is powered by magento 1.7.2, I thought that this question is not about magento, but I thought I should mention this.

Comment: This has been covered quite a bit here: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Awebmasters.stackexchange.com+prevent+index+development+site&oq=site%3Awebmasters.stackexchange.com+prevent+index+development+site&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.11943j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I really, REALLY hate the phrase "reach out"...